# Migrate to OpenJDK 11 from OpenJDK 8 for security reasons

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-security-oauth2, java-11

I received the advice some time ago to migrate to Java 11(OpenJDK) due to LTS. I'm confused that although Oracle stops LTS, OpenJDK provider(AdoptOpenJDK) remains LTS until very long time. https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html#roadmap

I remember securing spring boot with Java 8 had an issue and thus migrating to Java 11, but I couldn't found the documentation anymore.

Does anyone encounter the same and remember it?

**Update**: mentions OpenJDK with provider and use the better link @Elliott Frisch provides

Comment: OpenJDK is **not** LTS. OpenJDK provides source only. Are you looking for adoptOpenJDK? That is a distributor of the JDK. Specifically vendor neutral builds provided by RedHat (now a division of IBM). What are you looking for? I **think** you want [this](https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html#roadmap).

Comment: this link's info is also mentioned in wiki. The column has java8(LTS), why is not LTS?  I still remember an issue in spring boot security with java8 causes the move from java8 to java11

Comment: When you say long term support, whos' support do you expect? Spring never promised Java 8 support of any kind. Oracle does. Various OpenJDK distributors do. No one else does. Nor are they obligated to. I could decide tomorrow that I am no longer interested in working with or supporting Java 8. And you can't stop me. We have no contracts. So, who should support what?

Comment: I get your point. LTS should be said together with OpenJDK providers. But what confuses me is when Oracle says stopped Java8 LTS this year, why people say java8 is dead and really start moving to java11, even though they don't use Oracle JDK8 and use AdoptOpenJDK?

Comment: Java 8 was released in March 2014. That is now six years ago. Java 11 in September 2018. Which is key. Because three months later (January 2019) Oracle stopped providing free public updates. The language evolved significantly in Java 9. As time progresses, there will be more and more incompatible changes. And Java 8 is no longer evolving (although supported by the community). Java 8 is dead in the sense that no new software should probably be written in it. You can keep using it for existing stuff for a few more years. But then what?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, does it mean "No new features" will be added to Java 8, however "Security Patches and bug fixes" will be provided by the openJDK providers (like AdoptOpenJDK, RedHat)?